# Integration when $\ln$ is in denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to integrate the function $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{\ln(x)} .$$

I have tried to do it by all methods (i.e. by substitution or by parts) but failed.

Comment: Hint: Let $x=e^u$.

Comment: Not solvable in closed form. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BX*X%2FLog%5BX%5D,+X%5D)

Comment: It is tantamount to finding $$\int \frac{e^{3y}}y\,dy$$ And that ain't gonna happen anytime soon.

Comment: Maple says the result is $$-{\it Ei} \left( 1,-3\,\ln  \left( x \right)  \right) $$

Comment: That's the exponential integral, I still don't think that counts as a closed solution.

Comment: You have to integrate....is this a problem from the book?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to integrate:
$$\int \frac{x^2}{\ln{x}}~dx$$
We substitute $x=e^u$ and $dx=e^u~du$.
This gives:
$$\int \frac{e^{3u}}{u}~du \tag{1}$$
This is not solvable in terms of elementary functions, however it can be expressed in terms of the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $\operatorname*{Ei}(x)$.
Using it's definition:
$$\int \frac{e^{3u}}{u}~du=\operatorname*{Ei}(3u)+C$$
Substituting back for $x$ gives the solution.